# SQL Count from INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, count

How can I select the count from an inner join with grouping?

```
SELECT COUNT(table1.act) FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.act = table2.act
GROUP BY table1.act
```

This will return the count of act's found in table2.

Adding

```
 SELECT table1.act, COUNT(table1.act) AS test
```

Returns

```
act     test
------- ----
17682   3
17679   3
17677   3
11636   1
11505   1
```

I want to receive the count of act's found total.

So I want to get 5. Can you help?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can wrap that query into another query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(table1.act) AS actCount FROM table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.act = table2.act
    GROUP BY table1.act
) t
```

Comment: Note that this will be a bit slow, but will work with whatever query you actually have in there. If it is as simple as that, notice you're just counting distinct table1.act that has a match in table2.act

Comment: Fast enough for what i'm doing. Query took 0.0142 sec. Thanks again!

Answer (score 11):

Use [count distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx)

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct table1.act) FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.act = table2.act
```

Comment: I tried that too. That returns.

    act     test
    ------- ----
    17682   1
    17679   2
    17677   1
    11636   1
    11505   1

Comment: That's strange. Something must have happened when you pasted the code. See this working demo on sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1ab86/1

Comment: Won't this return all of the distinct acts?

Comment: Thanks, this works for me in a similar query. Maybe @StevePayne forgot to remove the "GROUP BY" from his orignal query.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the entire query with a SELECT COUNT statement as shown in the answer from Mosty Mostacho, just wanted to post this answer with an ***as*** statement since normally it's better to return results with a column title.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as FilteredActs FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(table1.act) AS actCount FROM table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.act = table2.act
    GROUP BY table1.act
) T
```

Results:

[image: output results]

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(table2.act) FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.act = table2.act
```

Comment: I need the GROUP BY because there are multiple fields in table2 with the same act. In the above statement that would return 11.

Answer (score 1):

if you just want the result count,

```
SELECT     COUNT(1)
FROM       table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.act = table2.act
GROUP BY   table1.act
```

that should give you